# Код не работает в safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

Вот такой код:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  initCoursesTabs();

})

var initCoursesTabs = function() {
  var tabs = $('.tabs')

  for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
    var headings = $(tabs[i]).find('.tabs__headings');
    var content = $(tabs[i]).find('.tabs__content');

    $(headings[0]).addClass('is-active');

    $(content[0]).addClass('is-opened');
  }

  let newTabs = $('.tabs__content.is-opened')
  let prices = $('.courses__price')

  for (let i = 0; i < newTabs.length; i++) {
    let clone = $(newTabs[i]).clone();
    clone.find('.tabs__hours').remove();
    $(prices[i]).html(clone);
  }

  tabs.on('click', '.tabs__headings',function() {
    var index = $(this).parent().find('li').index(this);
    var content = $(this).parent().parent().find('.tabs__content');
    var clone = $(this).parent().parent().find('.tabs__price').clone();

    console.log(clone);

    $(this)
      .parent()
      .find('li')
      .removeClass('is-active')
    content
      .removeClass('is-opened')
    $(this)
      .addClass('is-active')
    $(content[index])
      .addClass('is-opened')
    $(this).parent()
      .parent()
      .parent()
      .parent()
      .find('.courses__price')
      .html(clone[index]);
  })
}
```

Работает везде, кроме мобильного Safari на iPhone5. Что тут не так?

Comment: А что именно не работает?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, это кусок кода, но из-за него не работает вообще все, что лежит в файле.

Comment: Я понимаю, что это кусок кода) Но важно понимать, что значит - не работает. Выдает ошибки: времени выполнения или синтаксические. Или ошибок нет и не работает какая-то часть в UI. Или сайт вообще не загружается.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko ошибки никакие не выдает, т.к. тестируется на реальном устройстве. Ошибок нет и не работает весь js

Comment: То, что вы не можете посмотреть ошибки на реальном устройстве не значит, что ошибок нет))

Answer (score 1):

Вся проблема в инициализации переменных через let (babel, ts на проекте нет).

```
var newTabs = $('.tabs__content.is-opened')
var prices = $('.courses__price')

for (var i = 0; i < newTabs.length; i++) {
  var clone = $(newTabs[i]).clone();
  clone.find('.tabs__hours').remove();
  $(prices[i]).html(clone);
}
```

Comment: в `for` забыл тоже поменять :)